# Given that $Z$ $\sim$ $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Find the expected value of $\phi$ $(Z)$ where $\phi$ is the CDF of $Z$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

So this was a homework problem and the given solution just had one line which read:

> Since $F(X)$ $\sim$  $unif(0,1)$ for any continuous random
>   variable $X$ with CDF $F$ thus the expected value is 1/2.

I don't understand this one line? What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Comment: @wolfies i think I switched 0 and 1 lol,my bad.

Comment: @wolfies thanks for pointing out, I had a good laugh about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall integration by parts, i.e., 
$$
\int u'v = uv - \int v'u.
$$
Now, 
$$
\mathbb{E}\Phi(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(z)f_Z(z)dz = \Phi^2(z)|^{\infty}_{-\infty} - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(z)f_Z(z)dz, 
$$
namely, 
$$
2\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(z)f_Z(z)dz = \lim_{z\to \infty}\Phi^2(z) - \lim_{z\to -\infty}\Phi^2(z) = 1- 0,
$$
thus
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(z)f_Z(z)dz =1/2\, . 
$$

For a simple explaination note that $\Phi(z) \in [0,1]$, and 
$$
P(\Phi(Z) \le \varphi)= P(Z \le \Phi^{-1}(\varphi)) = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\varphi))=\varphi,
$$
namely, the cdf of $X = \Phi(Z)$ is $\mathrm{U}[0,1]$, thus clearly its expectation is $1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a continuous real random variable with CDF $F$. Then $F$ is strictly increasing so we have for any $0 \leq t \leq 1$

$$\mathbb{P}(F(X)\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq F^{-1}(t)) = F(F^{-1}(t))=t,
$$

hence $F(X)$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.